# JS file and browser cache

Tags: javascript, caching, browser

Simple question: I have a javascript application that its size is 500 kb, is it possible to force the browser to store this file in cache?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Browser automatically stores your js into cache no need to force it

Answer (score 0):

try using those field in HTTP protocol to control the cache

```
Cache-Control:max-age=xxx
Expires:xxxx
Last-Modified:xxx
```

the browser will check those field to decide whether download a new file or just use the cache instead

Comment: ..what if i do not want browser to check each time to decide that needed to download a new content of that file